# Invoke-Command Powershell "Window Title Cannot be longer than X chacracters"

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, invoke-command

I am trying to run a script remotely using Powershell, the script still runs, but I receive an error `Invoke Command : Window Title cannot be longer than 1023 characters.`

Here is my code:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName Test -FilePath "\\Some\File\Path.ps1"`

I realize what is occuring when running the line in ISE, it places the `comments in the header` of the script into the files name.  Is there a way to prevent this action?  I can use the option `ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` which suppresses the error, but it also suppresses all other errors which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This web link albeit VBS, does provide clarity and a walk-through for your situation.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/06/02/how-can-i-display-more-than-1023-characters-in-a-custom-message-box/

This is a more common situation/issue than you would think.

HTH,

Kent

Comment: This link is now broken.

Comment: I was just able to get to the Technet link with no issue.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer.  This link no longer takes you directly to the article to which you are referring.

Comment: I apologize - I have corrected and updated the TechNet Link.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the Window Title explicitly? That should avoid the window title being anything except what you specifically want.

```
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Windows PowerShell';
```

Answer (score 0):

I know adding another answer may not always be agreeable, but had another thought about this..

Instead of displaying a Message Box to the user, you could craft an HTML file and display to the user..

```
get-service | ConvertTo-Html -Title "Services" -Body "<H2>The result of get-service</H2> " -Property Name,Status | 
foreach {if($_ -like "*<td>Running</td>*"){$_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=green>"}elseif($_ -like "*<td>Stopped</td>*"){$_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=red>"}else{$_}} > c:\services.html

get-service | ConvertTo-Html -CssUri "SS64.css" > c:\services.html
Invoke-Item c:\services.html
```

Ref. http://ss64.com/ps/convertto-html.html

Answer (score 0):

Running Powershell in Azure, I've fixed the problem by typing "exit" and the "enter" to create a new session.